# How can you turn a macOS SwiftUI view into an Image?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, screenshot, nsimage

I know that you can turn an iOS SwiftUI `View` into an image by following [these](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image) steps, but this uses UIKit things in the SwiftUI extension which you cannot use in SwiftUI for macOS.

Does anyone know how to snapshot/screenshot a macOS SwiftUI View?

Comment: That link is for SwiftUI

Comment: @loremipsum yes but it includes UIKit things which macOS SwiftUI cannot use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In macOS same approach can be used. `NSHostingController` is analog of `UIHostingController`. Also to get it drawn the view should be added to some window:

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> NSImage? {
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: self)
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        let contentRect = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: contentRect,
            styleMask: [.borderless],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false
        )
        window.contentView = controller.view
        
        guard
            let bitmapRep = controller.view.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: contentRect)
        else { return nil }
        
        controller.view.cacheDisplay(in: contentRect, to: bitmapRep)
        let image = NSImage(size: bitmapRep.size)
        image.addRepresentation(bitmapRep)
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried so many different code snippets to try to get this to work but this one finally did something. However, I needed to put everything from `controller.view.cacheDisplay` onward into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block and return the result in a completion handler. I also hardcoded the targetSize for now because my view wasn't returning the right `intrinsicContentSize`, but that's an unrelated issue.

Comment: Okay, it turns out if you set the size of the view explicitly with `.frame(...)`, then not only does `intrinsicContentSize` work, but you can also call `window.contentView?.layout()` (without it crashing for lack of defined size) to make it work without using `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Answer (score 0):

#### SwiftUI native snapshot technique for macOS 13.0+

Use SwiftUI's [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer) object to rasterize a macOS View into a NSImage.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@MainActor final class BitmapImage : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var images: [String: NSImage] = [:]

    init() {
        let view = SampleView()
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: view)
        
        #if os(macOS)
            renderer.scale = NSApplication.shared
                                          .mainWindow?
                                          .backingScaleFactor ?? 2.0
        
            if let nsImage = renderer.nsImage {
                images["1"] = nsImage
            }
        #endif
    }
}
```

---

```
struct SampleView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("picture")
            VStack {
                Divider()
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.custom("", size: 72))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
@available(macOS 13.0, *) struct ContentView : View {
    
    @StateObject private var bitmapImage = BitmapImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let nsImage = bitmapImage.images["1"] {
                Image(nsImage: nsImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 500)      // "Squeezed" Image test
            }
        }
    }
}
```